# How can I use variable outside that function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using this scope in controller:

```
$scope.uploadPic = function (file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://sites.net/upload',
                data: {file: file, blobType: 'apps'},
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                    var downloadLink = response.data.data.uploadInfo.publicDownloadUrl;
                    console.log(downloadLink);
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt, response) {
                // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
```

Yes, it works and I need this:

```
var downloadLink = response.data.data.uploadInfo.publicDownloadUrl;
console.log(downloadLink);
```

Ok but now, I have to use this `var` in another function. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Use a return statement?

Comment: Put `downloadLink` on `$scope`?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the variable outside your function:

```
var downloadLink;

$scope.uploadPic = function (file) {
    // ..
    file.upload.then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
            downloadLink = response.data.data.uploadInfo.publicDownloadUrl;
            // or, if you want to use it in your view:
            // $scope.downloadLink = downloadLink;
            console.log(downloadLink);
        });
    }, function (response) {
    // ..
}

function doSomethingWithLink() {
    var link = downloadLink;
    // do something with link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is document.variable

example inside function:

```
 document.downloadLink = response.data.data.uploadInfo.publicDownloadUrl;
```

example outside function:

```
document.downloadLink=  response.data.data.uploadInfo.publicDownloadUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it in `$scope` like

```
$scope.downloadLink = response.data.data.uploadInfo.publicDownloadUrl;
```

so it can be used globally in the file as well as on the **template** too.

**OR**

You can declare it in outside the function to use it globally